# How to return value from callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, callback

How I can return value from callback function?

The code

```js
function storeData(data) {
  const id = "5f354b7470e79f7e5b6feb25";

  const body = { name: "john doe" };

  bucket.insert(id, body, (error, result) => {
    console.log(error, result); // i want to return error & result from this callback
  });
}

export default {
  async createAd(_, { data }, { request }) {
    try {
      const dataa = await storeData(data);

      return; // to here
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Here I need to return the value(error, result) comes from `bucket.insert` callback to function `createAd` and return that value from there.

```
 bucket.insert --> createAd
```

How should it actually work

- when `createAd` function invokes
- `createAd` function should call `storeData(data)` function where data stores in DB
- after storing the data with function `bucket.insert`
- `bucket.insert` callback return the value `error` and `result`
- `storeData` should return the `bucket.insert` callback values to `createAd`
- `createAd` return value should contians the `storeData` return value

`bucket.insert` should contain a callback else it throws an error  `Third argument needs to be an object or callback.`

solution tried

- promisifing bucket.insert with nodejs util.promisify

Comment: Brute force conversion to promise: `return new Promise((res, rej) => bucket.insert(..., (error, result) => { if (error) rej(error) else res(result); }))`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom "Promisify".

E.g:

```
function storeData(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const id = "5f354b7470e79f7e5b6feb25";

    const body = { name: "john doe" };

    bucket.insert(id, body, (error, result) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      
      resolve(result)
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: thank this works :-)